# PDOException, could not find driver on PHP7

Tags: php, pdo, xampp

I'm using Slim framework and I got a PDO error. I just installed xamp on mac and I'm using PHP Version 7.

```
Type: PDOException
Message: could not find driver
File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/index.php
```

I checked my phpinfo and I have `pdo_mysql` enabled.

[image]

Comment: actually I'm making a connection like this `$dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$dbhost;Database=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);` it's an azure server.

Comment: In **php.ini**, remove `;` appending 
`;extension=pdo.so` like `extension=pdo.so`. May be. Ckeck.

Comment: @NanaPartykar how can that be? I just installed xamp. And I don't have extension=pdo.so in my php.ini

Comment: Find **php.ini** file, check whether `extension=pdo.so` is having `;`. If yes, then remove it. And, restart your `XAMPP`.

Comment: @NanaPartykar I don't have that in my php.ini.

Comment: means `extension=pdo.so` is not present. Then, add it and restart your server and check. May be. I am not sure.

Comment: @NanaPartykar tried your nonsense suggestion lol! nothing worked!

Comment: You're trying to connect to an `sqlsrv`?! That's quite something different than a MySQL server. Is the `PDO_SQLSRV` module installed and activated?!

Comment: @deceze no, no idea how to get it work, I'm on mac.

Comment: Then start here, because SQLSRV doesn't exist for Mac: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Comment: Update your post with the database conf variables.

Answer (score -2):

On a windows server you can add or uncomment the following lines in your php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

OR:

```
extension=pdo.dll
extension=pdo_mysql.dll
```

UPDATED:

For example code:

```
            'db'=>array(
                    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii_trackstar',
                    'emulatePrepare' => true,
                    'username' => 'yii',
                    'password' => '######',
                    'charset' => 'utf8',
            ),
```

Replace localhost by 127.0.0.1

before restart your XAMPP.

Comment: @AlienXu Sorry, I had not finished.

Comment: my server is not mysql

Comment: @AlienXu By you set pdo_mysql! What is your database?

Comment: azure server, mssql.